# Deriving the cosine formula using vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vectors

[image]
[image]

How did they go from 2**b⋅c** to -2bccosA? Where did they get the negative sign from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that $b$ and $c$ do not point in the 'same' direction. The scalar product of $b$ and $c$ is proportional to the angle *between* $b$ and $c$, but here the angle $A$ is not *between* $b$ and $c$ but rather the supplementary angle.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the vector $\vec{b}$ points into the vertex $A$ whereas $\vec{c}$ points out. Thus, we apply the formula for the dot-product in terms of the interior angle between $-\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ hence $-\vec{b} \cdot \vec{c} = -bc\cos A$

Comment: It is not at all trivial to derive $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = ab \cos \theta$, that result is essentially equivalent to the law of cosines so this problem seems a bit silly. But, perhaps I misunderstand the context...